# Override broadcasting conventions in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have two Numpy arrays, `x` and `y`, where `x` is n-dimensional with n>=1 but unknown at "compile time", whereas `y` is one-dimensional. The first dimension of `x` is guaranteed to match the first (and only) dimension of `y`. I would like get their "sum", call it `s`, with the same dimension of `x` as follows:

```
import numpy as np

x  = np.random.randn(5,100,10)
y  = np.random.randn(5)

s = np.empty_like(x)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
   s[i] = x[i] + y[i]
```

But I would like to avoid the for loop both for readability and, more importantly, for speed reasons.

Obviously because of how the broadcasting conventions in Numpy work, I cannot do `x+y`. This would either throw an error or, worse, would work by coincidence giving an unintended result.

I found two relatively nice one liners,

```
s1 = (x.T + y).T
s2 = x + y[(slice(0, y.shape[0]),) + (np.newaxis,)*(x.ndim-1)]
```

which are not bad. The first one is exploiting the fact that it's indeed the *first* dimension in `x` that matches the only dimension in `y`. It would not work otherwise. The second is more general, but it's quite verbose.

Since I am still in the process of learning Python and Numpy, I would like to know if there are other (ideally better, but I am also interested in general) alternatives to do what I want to do. Essentially what I am maybe looking for is a way to override the broadcasting conventions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the broadcasting rules.  So one way or other you have to add trailing dimensions to `y`.

You've used `newaxis`, producing:

```
In [9]: y[:,None,None].shape
Out[9]: (5, 1, 1)
```

Constructing a similar tuple for `reshape` may be a bit simpler:

```
In [10]: y.reshape((-1,1,1)).shape
Out[10]: (5, 1, 1)
```

`expand_dims` is another way of specifying the `reshape`:

```
In [11]: np.expand_dims(y,(1,2)).shape
Out[11]: (5, 1, 1)
```

None of these are computationally expensive, even if the code ends up a bit wordy.

There are several `atleast` functions, but it doesn't help:

```
In [19]: np.atleast_3d(y).shape
Out[19]: (1, 5, 1)
```

Still, looking at the code for `expand_dims` or this `atleast` may give you ideas of how to add dimensions.  One way or other they use `newaxis` or `reshape`.

You can also specify dimensions with `np.array`, but that adds the leading dimensions:

```
In [22]: np.array(y, ndmin=3, copy=False).shape
Out[22]: (1, 1, 5)
```

### edit

Using `x.ndim`:

```
In [30]: dim=[1]*x.ndim; dim[0]=-1;y.reshape(dim).shape
Out[30]: (5, 1, 1)
In [44]: y.reshape((-1,)+(1,)*(x.ndim-1)).shape
Out[44]: (5, 1, 1)

In [33]: np.expand_dims(y,tuple(np.arange(1,x.ndim))).shape
Out[33]: (5, 1, 1)
In [36]: np.expand_dims(y,list(range(1,x.ndim))).shape
Out[36]: (5, 1, 1)
```

Your version, slightly simplified:

```
In [45]: y[((slice(None),)+(None,)*(x.ndim-1))].shape
Out[45]: (5, 1, 1)
```

This is, in timings, the fastest.